# Is it a good way to keep thread-safety to synchronize the object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, shared-ptr, atomic

According to [shared_ptr/atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic), we know that `shared_ptr::reset()` is thread-safe.
To prevent the object being accessed by other threads from being released. I create a `store` ptr to preserve the expired object.
So, the following codes are thread safe in any of time?

```cpp
class data_info
{
    shared_ptr<sample> using;
    shared_ptr<sample> store;
}

// function1 and function2 are used in different threads;
void function1(data_info &a)
{
    a.using->do_something();
}

void function2(data_info &a)
{
    a.store = a.using;
    a.using.reset(new sample());
}
```

I write a demo to confirm my thought

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

#define ATOMIC_READLOCK(stored_data_ptr) \
    {                                    \
        auto atomic_readlock_##name = stored_data_ptr;

#define ATOMIC_READLOCK_RELEASE() \
    }

#define ATOMIC_WRITELOCK(stored_data_ptr, new_data_ptr) \
    stored_data_ptr = new_data_ptr

class bar
{
public:
    bar() : num(1) {}
    explicit bar(int x) : num(x) {}
    int get_num()
    {
        return num;
    }
    void set_num(int x)
    {
        num = x;
    }

private:
    int num;
};

vector<int> v;

shared_ptr<bar> ptr_1, ptr_2;

void get_func()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        ATOMIC_READLOCK(ptr_1);
        v.push_back(ptr_1->get_num());
        ATOMIC_READLOCK_RELEASE();
    }
}

void set_func()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        ptr_2 = make_shared<bar>(i);
        ATOMIC_WRITELOCK(ptr_1, ptr_2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(get_func);
    std::thread t2(set_func);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

But it occurs a core dump

```sh
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./reset'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000555a2a075c58 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() ()
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f70244ec700 (LWP 30265))]
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000555a2a075c58 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() ()
#1  0x0000555a2a0758b9 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() ()
#2  0x0000555a2a075790 in std::__shared_ptr<bar, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() ()
#3  0x0000555a2a0757c2 in std::shared_ptr<bar>::~shared_ptr() ()
#4  0x0000555a2a0753cc in get_func() ()
#5  0x0000555a2a076069 in void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)()>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)()) ()
#6  0x0000555a2a075b3e in std::__invoke_result<void (*)()>::type std::__invoke<void (*)()>(void (*&&)()) ()
#7  0x0000555a2a077b52 in decltype (__invoke((_S_declval<0ul>)())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)()> >::_M_invoke<0ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul>) ()
#8  0x0000555a2a077af0 in std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)()> >::operator()() ()
#9  0x0000555a2a077a3c in std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)()> > >::_M_run() ()
#10 0x00007f70251706df in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#11 0x00007f7024c836db in start_thread (arg=0x7f70244ec700) at pthread_create.c:463
#12 0x00007f70249aca3f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is thread-safe. But I also suggest another solution in which the thread to access the class member will get ownership of `shared_ptr`. It inherently makes the whole scenario thread-safe.

```cpp
void function1(data_info &a) {
    auto member = a.member;
    member->do_something();
}

void function2(data_info &a) {
    a.member = std::make_shared<sample>();
}
```

Comment: In your codes, what if when function1(thread1) is `do_something`, function2(t2) release this object what function1 is using now

Comment: @Smilencer 1. `auto member` in `function1` takes the ownership. 2. `function2` releases the ownership. But since `function1` holds `auto member` and `auto member` holds the reference count so the object below won't be freed.

Comment: but in this case you''l do smth with `auto member` , not with `a.member`

Comment: @Алексей Неудачин I don't see there is any difference there.

Comment: we dont see `sample` rollout so it's hard to read. yeah it will work

Answer (score -1):

but how you'll remove reserve `shared_ptr` then. reserve may go out of scope exactly when `.dosmth()` is called somewhere.
to do this stuff you need `weak_ptr`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291791/does-weak-ptrs-lock-will-always-work-in-statement-instore-com-r-lock-i?noredirect=1#comment111921096_63291791

upd:
yeah looks like it's thr safe

upd2:
so what we have here:
for `weak_ptr`'s `.lock()` ref counter of its `shared_ptr` gains +1 while stuff with `lock()` isn't finished (see link).
for `->` of `shared_ptr` it doesn't. Have tested it just now.

So it's not thread safe and it will not work.
to see it `dosmth()` should run longer than all others and use `this`